# Declare a List of Uuid's from the uuid package

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using image_picker library to pick multiple images and using the uuid library to assign a unique uuid to each image. I have a line which is the following :

```
final String ImageUuid = _uuid.v4();
```

which is equipped to return uuid for a single image.
So,
I have to transform the above to take a List of uuid's for every image that is picked.
So I did,

```
List<String> ImageUuid = _uuid.v4();
```

which rightfully gives an error of A Value of String cannot be assigned to List.

Here is my declaration for the above line :

```
static const Uuid _uuid = Uuid();
```

How do I obtain a list of uuid using the declaration above for subsequent usage ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `uuid` package itself shows an example on how to generate multiple UUIDs and add them to a `Set` [here](https://github.com/Daegalus/dart-uuid/blob/main/test/uuid_test.dart#L182) (on line 182).

```dart
final numToGenerate = 3 * 1000 * 1000;
final values = <String>{}; // set of strings
var generator = Uuid();

var numDuplicates = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < numToGenerate; i++) {
  final uuid = generator.v4();

  if (!values.contains(uuid)) {
    values.add(uuid);
  } else {
    numDuplicates++;
  }
}
```

You can then assign each element of the `Set` to your images.